# ResNet50: Transfer learning with GradCam

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new to the field and am having trouble applying GradCam to a Tensorflow ResNet50 model I have re-trained.

I have created my model as follows:

```
IMG_SHAPE = IMG_SIZE + (3,)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
```

```
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
```

```
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
prediction_batch = prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)
```

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = preprocess_input(x)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

```
base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
model.summary()

Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 sequential (Sequential)     (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 tf.__operators__.getitem (S  (None, 224, 224, 3)      0         
 licingOpLambda)                                                 
                                                                 
 tf.nn.bias_add (TFOpLambda)  (None, 224, 224, 3)      0         
                                                                 
 resnet50 (Functional)       (None, 7, 7, 2048)        23587712  
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (G  (None, 2048)             0         
 lobalAveragePooling2D)                                          
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 2048)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 5)                 10245     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 23,597,957
Trainable params: 19,463,173
Non-trainable params: 4,134,784
_________________________________________________________________
```

For the application of GradCam in the following tutorial:
https://github.com/ismailuddin/gradcam-tensorflow-2/blob/master/notebooks/GradCam.ipynb
the output of the last convulution layer is now required

```
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer("conv5_block3_out")
last_conv_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(model.inputs, last_conv_layer.output)
```

The problem I have, however, is that this last convulutional layer in my model is in the "resnet50 (Functional)", which I cannot access.

I can only access this layer if I use the unmodified ResNet50 base model which I cannot use for my project.

```
Model: "resnet50"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 224, 224, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)      (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1_conv (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 64  9472        ['conv1_pad[0][0]']              
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv1_bn (BatchNormalization)  (None, 112, 112, 64  256         ['conv1_conv[0][0]']             
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv1_relu (Activation)        (None, 112, 112, 64  0           ['conv1_bn[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 pool1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)      (None, 114, 114, 64  0           ['conv1_relu[0][0]']             
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 pool1_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           ['pool1_pad[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 conv2_block1_1_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 56, 56, 64)   4160        ['pool1_pool[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2_block1_1_bn (BatchNormal  (None, 56, 56, 64)  256         ['conv2_block1_1_conv[0][0]']    
 ization)                                                                                         
                                                                                                  
 conv2_block1_1_relu (Activatio  (None, 56, 56, 64)  0           ['conv2_block1_1_bn[0][0]']      
 n)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2_block1_2_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 56, 56, 64)   36928       ['conv2_block1_1_relu[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 conv2_block1_2_bn (BatchNormal  (None, 56, 56, 64)  256         ['conv2_block1_2_conv[0][0]']    
 ization)                                                                                         
...
 conv5_block3_2_relu (Activatio  (None, 7, 7, 512)   0           ['conv5_block3_2_bn[0][0]']      
 n)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv5_block3_3_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 7, 7, 2048)   1050624     ['conv5_block3_2_relu[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 conv5_block3_3_bn (BatchNormal  (None, 7, 7, 2048)  8192        ['conv5_block3_3_conv[0][0]']    
 ization)                                                                                         
                                                                                                  
 conv5_block3_add (Add)         (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           ['conv5_block2_out[0][0]',       
                                                                  'conv5_block3_3_bn[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 conv5_block3_out (Activation)  (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           ['conv5_block3_add[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling  (None, 2048)        0           ['conv5_block3_out[0][0]']       
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 predictions (Dense)            (None, 1000)         2049000     ['avg_pool[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 25,636,712
Trainable params: 25,583,592
Non-trainable params: 53,120
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

What do I have to do to access this layer in my model?

I would be infinitely grateful for a solution.

Comment: I think there might be no direct solutions from above model definition. I've raised a ticket on github. [CHECK.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16355). For workaround solutions, [TRY THIS](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16355#issuecomment-1086863960).

Comment: @Innat Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible not to insert the base_model as a functional in the model? Or does a base_model on which my own classifier is built always become a functional within a model?